# Extract values that satisfy a condition from numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

Say I have the following arrays:

```
a = np.array([1,1,1,2,2,2])
b = np.array([4,6,1,8,2,1])
```

Is it possible to do the following:

```
a[np.where(b>3)[0]]
#array([1, 1, 2])
```

Thus select values from `a` according to the indices in which a condition in `b` is satisfied, but using exclusively `np.where` or a similar `numpy` function?

In other words, can `np.where` be used specifying only an array from which to get values when the condition is `True`? Or is there another `numpy` function to do this in one step?

Comment: Use [`boolean indexing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays) : `a[b>3]`?

Comment: All you need do is run the code to answer your own question

Comment: Yes I know I can use boolean indexing, but my question specifies `but using exclusively np.where or a similar numpy function?`

Comment: @Gerald Can you give some background information why you need/want to do it in a single function call?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, there is a function: [`numpy.extract(condition, array)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.extract.html) returns all values from `array` that satifsy the condition.

There is not much benefit in using this function over `np.where` or boolean indexing. All of these approaches create a temporary boolean array that stores the result of `b>3`. `np.where` creates an additional index array, while `a[b>3]`and `np.extract` use the boolean array directly.

Personally, I would use `a[b>3]` because it is the tersest form.

Comment: @Gerald Please see the updated answer. I made a mistake in comparing performance: `np.extract` was slowest because I compared `b>a` instead of `b>3`. There is no big difference in performance when you actually compare the same thing ;)

Answer (score 5):

Just use boolean indexing.

```
>>> a = np.array([1,1,1,2,2,2])                                                                                                   
>>> b = np.array([4,6,1,8,2,1])                                                                                                   
>>>                                                                                                                               
>>> a[b > 3]                                                                                                                      
array([1, 1, 2])
```

`b > 3` will give you `array([True, True, False, True, False, False])` and with `a[b > 3]` you select all elements from `a` where the indexing array is `True`.

Answer (score 1):

Let's use list comprehension to solve this -

```
a = np.array([1,1,1,2,2,2])
b = np.array([4,6,1,8,2,1])
indices = [i for i in range(len(b)) if b[i]>3]  # Returns indexes of b where b > 3 - [0, 1, 3]
a[indices]
    array([1, 1, 2])
```