# Print indexed values from .txt file

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am a total beginner at Python and need to display certain indexes' values in a .txt file. I can display the index position of the values matching the defined criteria, but cannot print the indexed value itself.

```
np.where(sunspots > 200)
(array([ 352, 1055, 2380, 2494, 2501, 2504, 2505, 2506, 2507, 2508, 2515,
    2516, 2520], dtype=int64),)
```

This is what I have so far, and the result, but I would like to display the values at each indexed position.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_handling.asp

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/enumerate-in-python/

Comment: Hey. Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54090388/extract-values-that-satisfy-a-condition-from-numpy-array

Comment: Thank you! It is hard to find things similar to your problem for a beginner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can view indexes as well as values in multiple ways. I have listed a few below for your reference.

```
#created a sample list
sunspots = np.array([10,20,200,230,240,100,210,300,250])
np.where(sunspots > 200) # This will give the indices.
```

Now refer back to the original list of values like below to get the values

```
#To get the values
sunspots[np.where(sunspots > 200)]
```

You could also use enumerate and ndenumerate functions to view the indices and their values

```
# To print the index and values using enumerate
for i,x in enumerate(sunspots):
    print(i, x)
Output:
0 10
1 20
2 200
3 230
4 240
5 100
6 210
7 300
8 250

# To print the index and values using ndenumerate
for i,j in np.ndenumerate(sunspots):
    print(i,j)
Output:
(0,) 10
(1,) 20
(2,) 200
(3,) 230
(4,) 240
(5,) 100
(6,) 210
(7,) 300
(8,) 250
```